# YouTube video player with cardview mechanism stopping without reaction

Tags: android, youtube-api, android-cardview

I had tried to build a project in which 6 different videos from YouTube will be available in cardview style. Then the selected will play. But due to some error or mistake it is crashing.

Error is showing in the below given code in the last part where the intent code .

```
package com.chandra.user.newstrailerapp.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeInitializationResult;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeStandalonePlayer;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailLoader;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubeThumbnailView;

/**
 * Created by USER on 11-11-2016.
 */

public class YoutubecardAdapter extends     
RecyclerView.Adapter<YoutubecardAdapter.VideoInfoHolder> {

    //VIDEO IDs

    private String[] VideoId = {"AbzdfUNsSsM",
            "6QgLkw-rfc4",
            "nubDFeiUAsI",
            "poLjq0u4_5A",
            "r4O4Xec60_k",
            "1Q8fG0TtVAY",
            "MQEFmHsseaU"};
    Context ctx;

    public YoutubecardAdapter(Context context) {
        this.ctx = context;
    }

    @Override
    public VideoInfoHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView =      LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.yotube_card, parent, false);
        return new VideoInfoHolder(itemView);
    }

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final VideoInfoHolder holder, final int position) {
    final YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener onThumbnailLoaderListner = new YouTubeThumbnailLoader.OnThumbnailLoadedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onThumbnailError(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader.ErrorReason errorReason) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onThumbnailLoaded(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, String s) {
            youTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }
    };

    holder.youTubeThumbnailView.initialize(ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.YOUTUBE_API_KEY), new YouTubeThumbnailView.OnInitializedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader youTubeThumbnailLoader) {

            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setVideo(VideoId[position]);
            youTubeThumbnailLoader.setOnThumbnailLoadedListener(onThumbnailLoaderListner);
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {
            //write something for failure
        }
    });
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return VideoId.length;
}

public class VideoInfoHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    protected RelativeLayout relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView;
    YouTubeThumbnailView youTubeThumbnailView;
    protected ImageView playButton;

    public VideoInfoHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        playButton = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnYoutube_player);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        relativeLayoutOverYouTubeThumbnailView = (RelativeLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.relativeLayout_over_youtube_thumbnail);
        youTubeThumbnailView = (YouTubeThumbnailView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.youtube_thumbnail);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent((Activity) ctx, ctx.getResources().getString(R.string.YOUTUBE_API_KEY), VideoId[getLayoutPosition()]);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: What is the error message that you got?

Comment: In the last few lines of intent statement it is showing error.